# Find m satisfied $\dim(U^\perp) = 2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $U = \operatorname{span} \{(1; -1; 2; 0), (3, 0, 1, m), (1, 2, -3, 0)\}$ If $\dim(U^\perp) = 2\}$

Find $m$.

I don't sure how to solve this problem. Here is my idea:

Because $\dim(U^\perp) + \dim(U) = n$, if $U$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ And I guess $U$ is subspace of $\mathbb R^4$, so, $\dim(U)$ will be equal to $2$. After that, so after transform U to reduce echelon matrix, will contain exactly $2$ leading one.

I don't sure this way is true or wrong.

Thanks :)

Comment: If you write "dim U" in LaTeX, you get $dim U$, but if you write \dim U, you get $\dim U$.  Not only is $\dim$ not italicized but also there's proper spacing before and after it.  This is standard usage in LaTeX.  I also did a few other TeX edits.

Comment: You know that $\dim(U)=2$, so those three vectors are linearly dependent. The rest is simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is good. Your set already contains two linearly independent vectors. If $m$ was chosen so that the third vector is also linearly independent then the complement will be of dimension only $1$. You need to choose $m$ so that the vector lies in the span of the other two.